# From multiple values per rows of a pandas dataframe: get two columns with every realation of the values (to analyse the network with Networkx)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, networkx

I have a dataframe with names of persons in it. The persons work thogether on the same item.

```
item   names
a      moriz, jon, cate 
b      jon, lenard 
c      cate, martin, leo, jil
```

- I like to prepare the names for a network-visualisation. I need to split the name-cells up in in two rows: in a way, that every relation is shown. like this:

```
item    person 1    person 2
a       moriz       jon
a       moriz       cate
a       jon         cate
b       jon         lenard
c       cate        martin
c       cate        leo
c       cate        jil
c       jil         martin
c       jil         leo
c       martin      leo
```

- I know how to split the name-cell in multiple name-cells for each item. But I don't know how to list them in pairs with every relation per item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this (`df` your dataframe):

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import combinations

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'item': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
        'names': ['moriz, jon, cate', 'jon, lenard', 'cate, martin, leo, jil']
    }
)

df.names = df.names.str.split(", ").map(lambda l: list(combinations(l, 2)))
df = df.explode("names")
df[["person 1", "person 2"]] = df.names.str.join(",").str.split(",", expand=True)
df = df.drop(columns="names")
```

Result for the sample:

```
  item person 1 person 2
0    a    moriz      jon
0    a    moriz     cate
0    a      jon     cate
1    b      jon   lenard
2    c     cate   martin
2    c     cate      leo
2    c     cate      jil
2    c   martin      leo
2    c   martin      jil
2    c      leo      jil
```

Comment: The first line doesn't work. The first part of the first line (str.split) works. But the second (map(lambda...) does not. TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable. Any idea?

Comment: @Tsiss Worked for the sample? Did you accidentally type ˋ1ˋ instead of ˋlˋ in ˋcombinations(l, 2)ˋ?

Comment: I have tryed it first on the original df: it didn't work.  But really: it works for the sample! Maybe the NAN's are the problem ore the lines with just one name in the original df.

Comment: @Tiss In which column(s) can the `NaN` appear?

Comment: thanks! I just deleted all rows with NaN bevore I used your code. And it worked!